# How can you find all world treasures?

Tags: achievements, infinity-blade

One of the achievements in Infinity Blade is *Waste Not Want Not*. The description for it is  "find all world treasures in a play through."  After you get the first treasure, though, you have to choose from a fork: either go through the front door or go into the basement dungeon.  Both paths have treasures, but you can't play both paths---can you?  How is it possible to attain this achievement?

Comment: I am level 264 and reached game+ 5 times ..i can not find all tresures..i have completed all secret achievement ..only achievements left are the world tresure and the multiplayer ones...i think something is wrong with the tresure achievement..

Answer (score 3):

The achievement only applies to the original game: the path into the basement dungeon is for Content Pack #2. So to complete *Waste Not Want Not*, go through the front door.

It should be noted that you need to find more than just treasure chests: to complete the achievement, you need to collect money bags and potions, as well.